# Does it have a name when you know certain vocabulary in another language but not in your own?

Tags: terminology

For example if you draw a venn diagram for all the vocabulary that you know in the languages that you consider yourself to be fluent in, you'll have some gaps in the "foreign" languages, but does it have a name when a gap is created in your mother tongue?

For example, somebody learning programming exclusively in English, being a native speaker of, say, Chinese. And then they get into a situation when they need to explain something programming-related in Chinese and they don't know a single word for anything in that field, despite being very proficient in it in English.

Comment: I suppose if you want something fancier than "gaps" you could go with "lacunae". L1 lacunae...